# angular-flot $.plot is not a function

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using [angular-flot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-flot) for chart but when i render the page it gives error

> $.plot is not a function.

AS I have jquery in my project.

Do I need to add *jquery.flot.js* and other files somewhere?

if yes than why we should use angular-flot?

Can't we use directly adding the jquery flot js and with $(function){ ... })

Comment: Do you have JQuery installed?

Comment: yes. jquery is installed